# Thread Overload at server

Tags: multithreading, jsp, servlets, jboss, jboss7.x

I am using the jsp-servlet in my application. and deployed the war on JBoss AS 7.0.2 server. i have servlet that is being called many time in sec (say 500 times). I think so this thread will not handled by the server. server throws an exception.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
     at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
     at java.lang.Thread.start(Unknown Source)
```

also i have added the max heap memory and set it to 1024. but it doesnot work for me. 
is any one know how the server will handle the such many threads?
am i on the right track here ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JBoss AS 7.0.2 runs out of threads durring database connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326833/jboss-as-7-0-2-runs-out-of-threads-durring-database-connection) from the same author

Answer (score 0):

"Native thread" hints that it's not JVM's thread. Therefore, JVM memory settings do not apply to that. At least not directly, see [this article](http://blog.egilh.com/2006/06/2811aspx.html).

1) Try reducing stack size;
2) Try decreasing memory limit.

Comment: This one is also good: http://candrews.integralblue.com/2009/01/preventing-outofmemoryerror-native-thread/